# What was the opening scene in The Mandalorian S03E06 referencing?

Tags: analysis, reference, the-mandalorian

In the opening scene of *The Mandalorian* (S03E06: Guns For Hire), viewers witness a situation where the former Night Owls or a group of Mandalorians led by Axe Woves gets involved in a situation where they are to bring back a Mon Calamari prince who ran away with a Quarren, whose surname is 'Shaggeth'...

The two characters seem to be "star-crossed lovers", but the scene itself also seemed like a parody, but I am curious to what this scene is all referencing and why it was included. A few ideas I had were:

- *Clone Wars* Episode (I seem to vaguely remember another royal Mon Calimari story).
- [Romeo and Juliet](https://www.slashfilm.com/1249150/mandalorian-romeo-juliet-romance-connects-clone-wars/), many British Period films and/or Anakin Skywalker & Padme's/Satine Kryze and Obi-Wan's tragic romance. (Star-Crossed Lovers, tragic love stories).
- Monty Python or *Austin Powers: The Spy Who SHAGGED Me* (British [Parody](https://wegotthiscovered.com/tv/the-mandalorian-may-have-dealt-itself-a-fatal-blow-by-becoming-a-full-blown-parody/?fbclid=IwAR2Kacpq2euIP21q3U2bco-2B2GWhJRUXpXjHjnV-_-_w2m8SrPpkFlGYyQ)).

#### Are any or all of these correct? Or is there something I am missing or more specific?

My guess as to what this means or might be foreshadowing is, either about getting back to what happened to Ezra Bridger (as he left with Thrawn via Purgells pushing them into hyperspace and Ahsoka and Sabine have been looking for them. Some fans feel that Sabine & Ezra were on the verge of a romantic relationship throughout *Star Wars Rebels*) and/or a star-crossed lover situation between Din Djarin and Bo-Katan, where the two may have feelings for each other, but will be separated in the near future.

In addition perhaps the *Romeo & Juliet* reference may represent some kind of gang violence like Mandos vs Mandos (ie: House of Montague vs House of Capulet).

Comment: You know Romeo and Juliet is a 16th Century Shakespeare play, not just a film, right?

Comment: Of course, and there are many adaptations, but what does that have to do with this? If you are refering to my link, then I was using Slashfilm as a reference point, in terms of not being the only one to notice this potential parallel. The first answer doesn't think there is anything specific and I was using these links to show that other viewers had noticed what I had noticed.

Comment: Because you said "Romeo & Juliet, a British Period film"

Comment: No, I was listing things that together or that are similar. Anakin & Padme and/or  Satine & Obi-wan are characters not plays or films, but I listed them with those other BRITISH works, because they have British-esqu stylization or tropes similar to to popular British period/romance films and/or something more specific like Romeo & Juliet star-crossed romantic tragedy plot.

Comment: Most British Period films are also adaptations of well-beloved books, but argumentatively, most people today probably recognize the style, story structure, or flavor better in film form. (ie: Jane Austen).

Comment: Some of these names crack me up anyway [Mon Calamari sounds like a Greek seafood restaurant] but are you *sure* the name was 'Shaggeth' [he shags (see Mike Myers)] rather than 'Shaggoth' [Lovecraftian monster]? I'm also surprised to see West Side Story missing from the canon refs. [[I'm aware, none of this helps]]

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's a parody of or reference to anything specific, as much as a very recognizable trope or storyline, with the usual genders reversed (i.e. normally it's a princess supposedly kidnapped by a scoundrel ship captain that she's in love with).

The plot is so well known that it was already being subverted and played with decades ago -- for example *The Princess Bride* is that story told from the pirate's point of view, and it was referenced by an episode of Star Trek TNG (where it turned out the scoundrel wasn't actually her lover, but rather the taxi driver trying to get Juliet to her Romeo's planet).

For that matter, from a certain point of view, *The Mandalorian* situation was an inversion of Leia's storyline, except the royalty in question isn't the heir to a destroyed planet with no relatives, so the family wants him back immediately.

Comment: I would be happy to know the name of this trope too! But I'm not the only one who made the Romeo and Juliet connection, so I do think there may be something more here, even if you are also right and there us also a more generalized subversion of a fantasy/history genre trope. But also thanks for the Leia plot point. I did not think of that before!
https://www.slashfilm.com/1249150/mandalorian-romeo-juliet-romance-connects-clone-wars/